# Bootstrap Bootstrap navbar Active State not changing after separating my sidebar code in sidebar.php

Tags: php

The content of sidebar is in another file sidebar.php

I have included sidebar.php in my main page dashboard.php.

Now the Bootstrap navbar menu Active State is not changing.

If I place the sidebar.php html code in dashboard.php it is working fine and menu state is also changing.

```
sidebar.php

<div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-image="assets/img/sidebar-5.jpg">

    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#" class="simple-text">
                <img src="img/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="dashboard.php">
                    <i class="pe-7s-info"></i>
                    <p>Dashboard</p>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="profile.php">
                    <i class="pe-7s-id"></i>
                    <p>Your Profile</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="change_passwd.php">
                    <i class="pe-7s-key"></i>
                    <p>Change Password</p>
                </a>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

my dashboard.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <?php require 'side_bar.php'; ?>

    <div class="main-panel">
        <?php require 'top_bar.php'; ?>


        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">

            </div>
        </div>

        <?php require 'footer.php'; ?>

    </div>
</div>


</body>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-checkbox-radio-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js"></script>
</html>
```